# Copy File From Local System to Online Server using Domain Name in VB.NET Application

Tags: vb.net, remote-server

I need to copy a file from local machine to online server.
i.e.
Source File Location : D:\backup\MyFile.doc
Destination File Location : www.abcd.com\backup\MyFile.doc 
I have already given Server Folder Read/Write Permission.

Please suggest

Comment: Do you have a FTP account to access the server?

Comment: I have but i don't want to use FTP. I want to do it programmatically unless if doesn't have any other option.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant: produce code to access the Server via FTP. See [FtpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest).

Comment: I want it through  VB.NET Windows Application....

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. That's what the `FtpWebRequest` class is for. If you saw code in the linked page in another language, you can find the Language selector in the upper band of all MSDN Docs pages related to .Net languages.